# Nearly Free Electron Approximation for 3D Lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrons, crystals, lattice-model

I have been learning the Nearly-Free Electron approximation method and its application in one dimensional lattices. Since nearly all real-world lattices are three-dimensional, I am trying to apply this approximation method to the simplest possible three-dimensional lattice: the simple cubic lattice. Specifically, I am trying to compute some energy bands of these electrons close to the edges of the first Brilluoin zone. Assume a lattice spacing of value $a$.

Here is what I planned.

Let $$\phi(\vec{r}) = \sum_{\vec{k}} C_{\vec{k}} e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \hspace{2.5cm}V(\vec{r}) = \sum_{\vec{G}}V_{\vec{G}}e^{i\vec{G}\cdot \vec{r}} s.t. |V_G| << \hbar^23(\pi / a)^2 / 2m$$

Hence the Schrodinger wave equation becomes the following:

$$\bigg[-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 + \sum_{\vec{G}}V_{\vec{G}}e^{i\vec{G}\cdot \vec{r}}\bigg]\sum_{\vec{k}} C_{\vec{k}} e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} = E\sum_{\vec{k}} C_{\vec{k}} e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}\\
\bigg[\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\sum_{\vec{k}} C_{\vec{k}} e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}\vec{k}\cdot \vec{k} + \sum_{\vec{G},\vec{k}}V_{\vec{G}} C_{\vec{k}}e^{i(\vec{G+\vec{k})}\cdot \vec{r}}\bigg] = E\sum_{\vec{k}} C_{\vec{k}} e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}\\
\sum_{\vec{k}}\bigg[\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} C_{\vec{k}}\vec{k}\cdot \vec{k} + \sum_{\vec{G}}V_{\vec{G}} C_{\vec{k} - \vec{G}}\bigg] e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} = E\sum_{\vec{k}} C_{\vec{k}} e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}}\\
\therefore \bigg(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \vec{k}\cdot \vec{k} - E\bigg) C_{\vec{k}} + \sum_{\vec{G}}V_{\vec{G}} C_{\vec{k} - \vec{G}} = 0\\
$$

Now, for a simple cubic lattice with lattice spacing $a$, the reciprocal lattice vectors are $\vec{G} = n_1 (\frac{2\pi}{a}\hat{k}_x) + n_2 (\frac{2\pi}{a}\hat{k}_y) + n_3 (\frac{2\pi}{a}\hat{k}_z)$, where $n_1, n_2, n_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let me denote three-tuples of integers as $\vec{n}$. Hence the summation over $\vec{G}$ becomes a summation over $\vec{n}$. Hence I have the following:

$$\bigg(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \vec{k}\cdot \vec{k} - E\bigg) C_{\vec{k}} + \sum_{\vec{n}}V_{\vec{n}} C_{\vec{k} - \vec{G}_{\vec{n}}} = 0$$

Clearly these are infinite dimensional matrix equations of the form square matrix $\times$ vector
= 0.

Now, since I want to determine the energy $E$ near the first Brilloiun zone, I need to choose $\vec{k}$ to be $\pm \vec{G}/2$. Hence I want my $\vec{k}$ to be $n_1 (\frac{\pi}{a}\hat{k}_x) + n_2 (\frac{\pi}{a}\hat{k}_y) + n_3 (\frac{\pi}{a}\hat{k}_z)$, such that $n_1, n_2, n_3 \in \{1,-1\}$. Hence, the summation over $\vec{n}$ is a summation over $2^3 =  8$ different $\vec{n}$ vectors.

Using this scheme, my square matrix has been reduced from an infinite by infinite dimensional matrix to an $8 \times 8$ matrix. The determinate of such a matrix will lead to a characteristic polynomial equation of order 8. This will, in principle, give be at most the first 8 energy bands.  I can probably simplify the equation since I am assuming that the potential is weaker than the kinetic energy.

**Suppose, however, that I want to estimate the first three energy eigenvalues. Is there a way to deal with a smaller matrix? Basically, there exists no analytical formula for an order 8 polynomial equation, so I am wondering if there is an easier way.**

**Also, if the lattice is a simple cubic where the atoms at the vertices are identical, can I say that the Fourier coefficients $V_{\vec{G}}$ are all the same?**

Comment: No, I don't think so in regard to polynom 8th order. There are various ways of different treatments, but even if you make assumptions for simplifications it wouldn't simplify mathematically (the contrary).

Comment: Depends what you assume for $V_\vec G $, for a Kronig-Penney Model e.g. yes. see Kittel, Introduction to Solid State Physics, 2005, formula (33).